# Changing height of slider range thumb in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, slider

Is there a way to set the slider range thumb to height of 100% or
to change its heights dynamically in JavaScript ?

```
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This code doesnt work, because setting it to 100% makes it disappear.
So How could I change its height, when the slider height is dynamic.. ?

Comment: What is a slider for you? A slide of a Slide-Show?

Comment: As I told.. Im talking about a slider range input